# TON transfer bug when using 32 (DESTROY_ACCOUNT_IF_ZERO) flag?

Tags: javascript, blockchain, cryptocurrency, ton

I've been trying to reuse a wallet deleted by `DESTROY_ACCOUNT_IF_ZERO` (32) flag. The way I do the transfer:

Imagine we have 2 wallets: A and B.

1. We transfer `N1` TON from `A` to `B`. E.g. by using a web-based wallet, script, doesn't matter.
2. `B` is uninitialized - it is not on the blockchain yet. With that in mind, we'd like to send all the money from `B` back to `A`. For this we're going to use the attached script.
3. Now we go ahead and transfer `N2` TON from `A` to `B` **again**. Doesn't matter how much.

Expected behavior: we get transactions: `A->B (N1)`, `B->A (all)`, `A->B (N2)`; wallet `B` has `N2` TONs in the end.

Actual behavior: we get transactions `A->B (N1)`, `B->A (all)`, `A->B (N2)`, **`B->A (all)`; wallet `B` has `0` TONs in the end.**

The script for `B->A (all)` transfer, which causes this behavior:

```
import TonWeb from 'tonweb';
import tonwebMnemonic from 'tonweb-mnemonic';


const apiKey = "" || undefined;
// WALLET B
const mnemonic = "...";
const walletVersion = "v4R2";
// WALLET A
const toAddress = "...";


const SendMode = {
    CARRY_ALL_REMAINING_BALANCE: 128,
    CARRY_ALL_REMAINING_INCOMING_VALUE: 64,
    DESTROY_ACCOUNT_IF_ZERO: 32,
    PAY_GAS_SEPARATELY: 1,
    IGNORE_ERRORS: 2,
    NONE: 0
}

const sleep = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));


(async () => {
    const provider = new TonWeb.HttpProvider('https://toncenter.com/api/v2/jsonRPC', {apiKey});

    const WalletClass = TonWeb.Wallets.all[walletVersion];
    const mnemonicArray = mnemonic.split(" ");
    
    let { publicKey, secretKey } = await tonwebMnemonic.mnemonicToKeyPair(mnemonicArray);
    publicKey = Buffer.from(publicKey);
    secretKey = Buffer.from(secretKey);

    console.log(`PUBLIC KEY: ${publicKey.toString('hex')}`);

    const wallet = new WalletClass(provider, { publicKey });

    const seqno = await wallet.methods.seqno().call() || 0;
    console.log(`SEQNO: ${seqno}`);
    await sleep(2000);
    
    const transferParams = {
        secretKey,
        toAddress,
        amount: 0,
        seqno,
        sendMode: SendMode.CARRY_ALL_REMAINING_BALANCE | SendMode.IGNORE_ERRORS | SendMode.DESTROY_ACCOUNT_IF_ZERO,
        payload: "test bug"
    };

    console.log(JSON.stringify({...transferParams, secretKey: transferParams.secretKey.toString('hex')}, null, 2));

    const response = await wallet.methods.transfer(transferParams).send();    

    console.log(`transfer sent to blockchain: ${JSON.stringify(response, null, 2)}`);
})();
```

The strange thing is: if you send `A->B (N)` again, it will create a new transfer `B->A (all)` again and again automatically. Sometimes it stops at 2 repeats, sometimes at 4.

I use the unbounceable address: `UQAPqRlewultl8xHCKGsrenb4PZaQ0QDfPYoK1fwVUODdZRd`.

I also tried sending TON from wallet `C` (`C->B`). And the money DID stay on `B`. BUT once I made a transfer `A->B` again, all the money including the TONs sent from `C` went to `A` automatically!

An example of this bug's manifestation (is it a bug??) is here:

https://tonviewer.com/EQAySjlsHUY2EEedO5GTenzFvAnR5E-4ptwfeox6OZYnNvGF

This is `B` wallet. Only the first message with "test bug" text was sent by the script. The rest of them were sent automatically on any incoming transfer from `A`.

In this interaction:

- `A` is `UQAPqRlewultl8xHCKGsrenb4PZaQ0QDfPYoK1fwVUODdZRd`
- `B` is `EQAySjlsHUY2EEedO5GTenzFvAnR5E-4ptwfeox6OZYnNvGF`
- `C` is `UQBwpXsIVrij8UQ2OpPK2EyeVBrlN6mnOkmThb3k6K-UHZyL`

I want to understand, why this happens. Is this intended by TON blockchain developers? Is this not a bug? How to go around this and reuse deleted wallets?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this usecase is not the supported intent of `DESTROY_ACCOUNT_IF_ZERO`. From what I can find, `DESTROY_ACCOUNT_IF_ZERO` is designed for one-time/temporary accounts to reduce empty account clutter on the blockchain.

Comment: If `B` is a smart contract, you might be able to adjust the contract logic to handle incoming transfers differently. ‍♂️

Comment: @PCDSandwichMan A, B and C are regular TON `v4R2` wallet contracts. An interesting thought about these accounts being unrecoverable. Still, strange behavior, though. And lack any of docs on that matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a bug.

Incoming messages to the blockchain are kept for a while in node's mempool, until their TTL runs out.

Initial state of our wallet's smart contract is `seqno=0`.

Flag `DESTROY_ACCOUNT_IF_ZERO` (32) destroys account, so wallet's smart contract no longer exists in the blockchain. We make this transfer with `seqno=0`.

After the outgoing transfer is sent from the wallet, wallet's smart contract gets published to the blockchain **again**. Which in turn means its `seqno` becomes `0` **again**. So the previous messages, still in the mempool, get executed **again**.

So, it is, in fact, a really peculiar behavior of TON blockchain. It is very irregular, indeed, but in no way is it a bug.